# Error while linking with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I run the following command to link the different files in my project.

```
/opt/gcc-4.7-cilkplus/bin/gcc -g -Wall -l /opt/gcc-4.7-cilkplus/lib64/ -o exec main.o \
    mysql-client.o databaseConnection-common.o murmurhash3.o bloom-filter.o
    `mysql_config --cflags --libs\` -lcilkrts
```

Note the option *-l /opt/gcc-4.7-cilkplus/lib64/*

When I run this command I get this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/opt/gcc-4.7-cilkplus/lib64/

but this directory is present in my system. Can anyone please tell the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-l (el) should be followed by a library, not a directory.  Perhaps you meant -L or -I (eye)

Comment: `-L` tells the linker a directory to search.  It is almost certainly `-L`.

Comment: my bad. I got it now. Can you tell some other place to specify these linker library so that I do not have to include then by doing -L each time (like some path variable which gcc searches every time before linking).

Comment: LIBRARY_PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

You are using `-l` where you should be using `-L`. The option `-l` specifies a library, whereas `-L` specifies a directory in which to look for libraries.

Note also that there is no space between `-l` or `-L` and its respective value.

Answer (score 0):

`-Lpath/to/lib -lname` is the syntax (without spaces after `-L` and `-l`). If linking to a static library for example, this means that link should be done with `path/to/lib/libname.a`

Also, note that the order of arguments to linker is important. That is, if object `A` uses library `B`, `B` should be written after it. If `B` itself uses `C`, then first `A` should be mentioned, then `B` and then `C`.

Your command therefore would probably look like this:

```
/opt/gcc-4.7-cilkplus/bin/gcc -g -Wall -o exec main.o mysql-client.o \
databaseConnection-common.o murmurhash3.o bloom-filter.o \
`mysql_config --cflags --libs\` -L/opt/gcc-4.7-cilkplus/lib64/ -lcilkrts
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                Used -L and moved here
```